# Array not being assigned a value

Tags: php, arrays

Could you help see why the value is not being assigned to the array element?

My array print_r's like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [month] => May [year] => 2014 [count] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [month] => Apr [year] => 2014 [count] => 0 ) [2] => Array ( [month] => Mar [year] => 2014 [count] => 0 ) [3] => Array ( [month] => Feb [year] => 2014 [count] => 0 ) [4] => Array ( [month] => Jan [year] => 2014 [count] => 0 ) [5] => Array ( [month] => Dec [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [6] => Array ( [month] => Nov [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [7] => Array ( [month] => Oct [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [8] => Array ( [month] => Sep [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [9] => Array ( [month] => Aug [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [10] => Array ( [month] => Jul [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) [11] => Array ( [month] => Jun [year] => 2013 [count] => 0 ) )
```

I have some code that should add a value to count.

```
    foreach($archives as $archive){
        if ($archive['month'] == date('M', strtotime($post['timestamp']))){
            echo 'hello';
            $archive['count']++;
        }
    }
```

'hello' is outputted, but count doesnt receive the value. I also tried this but it didn't work.

```
$archive['count'] = 'hello';
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `foreach` iterates over a shallow copy of the array. Use `foreach($archives as &$archive)` to reference the original array's values.

Comment: [Be very careful with pointers in a loop! To be safe, you should `unset($archive)` in the loop, at the end.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `&` to directly modify array elements in the `foreach` loop :

```
foreach($archives as &$archive){
    if ($archive['month'] == date('M', strtotime($post['timestamp']))){
        echo 'hello';
        $archive['count']++;
    }
}
```

In that case `$archive` will be assigned by reference. **Also** the reference  of a `$archive` and the last array element remains after using `foreach` loop , so it is recommended to `unset` it.

Comment: [Be very careful with pointers in a loop! To be safe, you should `unset($archive)` in the loop, at the end.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this without `&` use next code

```
 foreach($archives as $key => $archive){
        if ($archive['month'] == date('M', strtotime($post['timestamp']))){
            echo 'hello';
        $archives[$key]['count']++;
        }
    }
```